# CakePHP 3 - array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0, cascade

I have an odd error in a CakePHP 3 Application I am developing and I can't figure what the issue is.The application and issue is as follows:

1. I have a Wishlist
2. That Wishlist can have many Wishlist Items
3. I am using Angular/Ajax to make a call and delete a WishlistItem

   ```
   http://domain.com/wishlist_items/delete/219
   ```
4. This does not work and it returns the following error:

   ```
   array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array 

   /­vendor/­cakephp/­cakephp/­src/­ORM/­Association/­DependentDeleteTrait.php 54
   ```
5. The `WishlistItemsController.php` in question is:

   ```
   public function delete($id = null) {
       $this->autoRender = false;

       $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
       $wishlistItem = $this->WishlistItems->get($id);

       if ($this->WishlistItems->delete($wishlistItem)) {
           echo json_encode(['message' => ['type' => 'success', 'text' => 'This wishlist item has been deleted successfully']]);
       }
       else {
           echo json_encode(['message' => ['type' => 'error', 'text' => 'This wishlist item could not be deleted']]);
       }
       return;
    }
   ```
6. The Wishlist Items have no dependents and the error is coming from this file `http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.ORM.Association.DependentDeleteTrait.html#19-57` line 54
7. My table files look like this:

   ```
   WishlistsTable.php

   $this->hasMany('WishlistItems', [
       'foreignKey' => 'wishlist_id',
       'dependent' => true,
       'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
   ]);

   ==================================================

   WishlistItemsTable.php

   $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
   $this->addBehavior('Ratings.Ratable');
   $this->belongsTo('Wishlists', [
       'foreignKey' => 'wishlist_id'
   ]);

   $this->addBehavior('CounterCache', [
       'Wishlists' => ['items_count']
   ]);
   ```

I cannot understand why `cascadeDelete` function is being used when this Table does not have any dependents.

STACKSTRACE:

```
Whoops\Exception\ErrorException thrown with message "array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array"

Stacktrace:
#15 Whoops\Exception\ErrorException in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association/DependentDeleteTrait.php:54
#14 Whoops\Run:handleError in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/gourmet/whoops/src/Error/WhoopsHandler.php:27
#13 Gourmet\Whoops\Error\WhoopsHandler:_displayError in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php:139
#12 Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler:handleError in <#unknown>:0
#11 array_merge in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association/DependentDeleteTrait.php:54
#10 Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany:cascadeDelete in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/AssociationCollection.php:273
#9 Cake\ORM\AssociationCollection:cascadeDelete in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php:1705
#8 Cake\ORM\Table:_processDelete in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php:1643
#7 Cake\ORM\Table:Cake\ORM\{closure} in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:557
#6 Cake\Database\Connection:transactional in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php:1648
#5 Cake\ORM\Table:delete in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/src/Controller/WishlistItemsController.php:139
#4 App\Controller\WishlistItemsController:delete in <#unknown>:0
#3 call_user_func_array in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php:429
#2 Cake\Controller\Controller:invokeAction in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php:114
#1 Cake\Routing\Dispatcher:_invoke in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php:87
#0 Cake\Routing\Dispatcher:dispatch in /var/www/domain.com/dev/website/webroot/index.php:37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were really only `BelongsTo` associations on the table object where you are calling `delete()`, then such a control flow should never happen, so there need to be more associations defined from elsewhere.

Given that the `Ratings.Ratable` behavior belongs to **[`dereuromark/cakephp-ratings`](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ratings)**, I'd suspect that the problem are the conditions that are being defined for the `HasMany` association that the behavior adds to the table:

**[https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ratings/.../Behavior/RatableBehavior.php#L85](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ratings/blob/93f2d9afe06e2ee9a1baf834c243a516aa555edd/src/Model/Behavior/RatableBehavior.php#L85)**

```
$this->_table->hasMany('Ratings', [
        'className' => $this->_config['rateClass'],
        'foreignKey' => $this->_config['foreignKey'],
        'unique' => true,

        'conditions' => '', // <<<<<< There it is

        'fields' => '',
        'dependent' => true,
        //'table' => 'sandbox_ratings'
    ]
);
```

That value ends up being passed to `array_merge()` as the second argument in `DependentDeleteTrait::cascadeDelete()`, hence the error.

So, that's a bug in the plugin, and I'd suggest that you report it. As a quick workaround, you could overwrite the conditions in your table class, like

```
$this->association('Ratings')->conditions([]);
```

Comment: I appreciate you being so thorough in your explanation and your willingness to help out. You are absolutely correct! 

During troubleshooting, I had removed this line `$this->addBehavior('Ratings.Ratable');` and since the issue continued, I assumed there was nothing wrong with it. However, I failed to notice that I had added it as a component in the `WishlistItemsController.php` file and the `Ratings.Ratings` component automatically loads a helper and behavior. 

Your quick workaround will do for now and I will report this issue to the creators of the Ratings plugin. Thank you so much!

Comment: The plugin creator was quick to put a fix out. Now  the Ratings plugin works without throwing any errors. Thanks again for catching that.
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ratings/issues/3